# Can I get Computers hardware detail from Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory

Is there any way to get hardware details from active directory? 
Is Active directory store hardware detials?

Comment: No, AD doesn't store hardware details about computers. It manages computer **accounts** - e.g. name, permissions, permissible login hours etc. - but it's **not** a computer / hardware inventory software

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't find anything about this solution. I review some applications that work with AD and get all PCs Hardware data, I think that Apps get details from AD. TNX again